# Could you show how nonstick Hard Anodized Aluminum is with an example? Say you leave pasta cooking for 1 hour

Tags: pasta, cookware, non-stick

- **goal -- im having a very very hard time finding out if 'Hard anodized aluminum' is nonstick, or if i should go with 'nonstick coating' on a jumbo cooker/pot**

heard that nonstick coating wears off over time

---

ppl say that 'Hard anodized aluminum' has 'nonstick' property -- https://www.quora.com/What-should-one-consider-when-shopping-for-cookware

but i can't tell if this is nonstick compared to 't-fal nonstick coating'

- **for example if you just forget and leave pasta in the jumbo cooker or pot at the regular temp most ppl use, would it stick?**

---

some say that 'anodized aluminum' is hard to clean -- http://thesweethome.com/reviews/best-cookware-set/

- **i cant tell if this is this is talking about 'Hard anodized aluminum' and if 'anodized aluminum' is a seperate concept**

---

this post -- cookydaddy.com/best-stainless-steel-cookware-vs-hard-anodized-cookware.html

seems like a promotional type of site but says that 'Hard anodized aluminum' is nonstick and thus easy to clean

Comment: Welcome! The question about nonstick quality and durability of hard anodized aluminum is a fine one, but I'm confused about pasta as an example here. You don't need a nonstick coating to keep pasta from sticking.

Comment: if you forget , leave  stove on, im sure it would tend to stick, yes? i have brunt pots many times because of this

Comment: I'm not sure even nonstick is going to save you from burned-on food. It's more about preventing sticking during normal cooking.

Comment: if you forget a cooking pot of pasta and cook it down so far that all the water is gone then whether or not your pot is non-stick or not irreverent and the least of your problems.

Comment: it seems ppl who have used HAA have said from their exp that if it was left cooking, it would not actually burn on, i dunno tho, HAA is not that new but it seems a lot of cook-type ppl are not experienced with HAA. the only source i've found so far that are experienced with HAA are amazon reviews, i'll have to get to reading the bunch of them

Comment: Quite frankly, you are the only reliable source for declaring it non-stick-enough-compared-to-X. It's an unanswerable question. If I find it non-stick enough, will it match your non-stickiness expectations? I think this question should be closed, unless you can quantify your expectations.

Comment: there's lots of questions that aren't quantified or is quantifable everywhere, just have to read a little -- there's also something call 'being helpful' above statistics and numbers

Answer (score 2):

If you leave pots of pasta to boil dry and burn, please avoid non-stick cookware. Most non-stick coatings turn to nasty toxic fumes if overheated.

I doubt there is any difference, besides marketing, between "hard anodized aluminum" and "anodized aluminum". The anodizing makes the surface much harder than natural aluminum.

I do not find much anodized aluminum (AA) cookware with an AA surface available new. Much with non-stick cooking surface available. And some lined with stainless steel. Calphalon used to be the big player, until they stopped making straight AA cookware. Then started and stopped again.

Speaking from experience of having a set of Calphalon AA cookware for twenty plus years, I would not consider AA non-stick. When frying, sauteing, etc, most things will stick, unless adequete oil, butter, or grease is used. With adequete fats I have not had a problem with sticking, except for eggs. Those are tricky buggers.

AA cookware generally can't go in the dishwasher. I have not find them especially hard to clean by hand. The green Scotch-Brite scubber pad does wonders. An occasional scrubbing with Comet keeps them pristine.